# Dismissable box removing first box and not one clicked

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Currently I have a while loop setup to display notations made on the page. When clicking the "x" to delete one, it always removes the first one from the page. The back end still deletes the correct entry however I have to refresh to see this. How I can prevent the wrong box from diapering to avoid confusion?

HTML/PHP while loop

```
while ($commentRow = mysql_fetch_array($woComments)) { ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-info panel-dismissable" id="panel-dismissable">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-target="#panel-dismissable" data-dismiss="alert" onClick="DelNotation(this, <?php echo $commentRow['CommentsID']; ?>);"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            Notation on <?php echo $commentRow['Date']; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p><?php echo $commentRow['Comment']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
<?php }
```

Ajax

```
     <!-- Close Notation -->
    <script>
function DelNotation(button, wo)
{
    var Comment = $(button).closest(".row").find(".panel-dismissable").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions/closeNotation.php",
        data: {wo: wo},
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            //alert("Your notation has been removed from this work order");
        }
    });
}


 </script>
```

Comment: Your using the same `id` over and over, you need to make it unique and the `data-target` needs to match it.

Comment: or change from id's to classes